# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{2^n+20^n-7^{-n}}{(-3)^n+5^n}}\;? $

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling to find following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{2^n+20^n-7^{-n}}{(-3)^n+5^n}} $$

Could anyone help me with a little explanation of that?

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{2^n+20^n-7^{-n}}{(-3)^n+5^n}}=O(\sqrt{4^n})=O(2^n)$

Comment: Please do not answer in comments, @KentaS

Comment: $\frac{(2/20)^n+1-(1/140)^n}{(-3/20)^n+(5/20)^n}$

Comment: Ditto, @Sumanta.  And you forgot the square root sign.

Comment: Could you give us a bit of your struggles?

Comment: Could it be that it actually is $\;\sqrt[n].\;$ instead of $\;\sqrt .\;$ ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{\frac{2^n+4^n-7^{-n}}{(-3)^n+5^n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{\frac{5^n\left((\frac{2}{5})^n+4^n-(\frac{1}{35})^n\right)}{5^n\left((\frac{-3}{5})^n+1\right)}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt{4^n}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Intuively in the numerator the $20^n$ will "dominate" and in the denominator the $5^n$ will dominate and so $\lim \sqrt\frac{ numerator}{denominator} =\lim \sqrt\frac {20^n}{5^n}=\lim \sqrt {4^n}=\lim  2^n = \infty$.

Now we can thumb through our texts to find the exact theorems and wording that allow us to say such dominating arguments are valid.

Answer (score 0):

In the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have

$$\begin{align}2^n+20^n-7^{-n} \rightarrow & 20^n \\
(-3)^n+5^n \rightarrow & 5^n  \end{align} $$

since $20^n$ and $5^n$ eventually become much larger than the other terms you're adding to them.

So

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{2^n+20^n-7^{-n}}{(-3)^n+5^n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{20^n}{5^n}} = \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it actually is the $\;n\,$ -th root:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n+20^n-7^{-n}}{(-3)^n+5^n}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{14^n+140^n-1}{(-21)^n+35^n}}=\frac{140}{35}\sqrt[n]{\frac{\left(\frac{14}{140}\right)^n+1-\left(\frac1{140}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{(-21)}{35}\right)^n+1}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{140}{35}=4$$